# How do I get out of third person view?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I've finally obtained the Werewolf form. After returning out of the form, fully naked...

I seem to be stuck in third person view! How can I fix this? Scrolling or pressing <kbd>F</kbd> does not work.

I want to get back in first person view...

---

Mouse wheel allows to zoom in/out but not get me into the first person view but rather behind and slightly to the right of the character. The command `animcam` locks me at a certain distance, doing it again brings me back into the mode that I'm stuck in third person view. Hitting <kbd>F</kbd> after this doesn't work. `tfc` doesn't help me either, although that command is nice to take screenshots...

Comment: Tom, I know it sounds daft but it's best to rule it out, have you tried reloading your game and seeing if pressing F then fixes the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using your mouse wheel to see if that changes the point of view? There is also a command for console mode (Brought up by hitting the tilde key) called animcam which toggles a camera effect on/off. Try toggling that on and off if the above doesn't work and then hitting F again?

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer: Got it fixed, I'm glad that I didn't have to restore the old save file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enter and leave werewolf mode again.**

Yes, it's as simple as that. Go to the magic menu and select the *Beast Form*, then press the button you use to cast a dragon shout. It might be necessary to do this at night or perahps inside a dungeon, then you can go outside and use the wait system to wait till it is day again. You should be able to zoom back into the character afterwards...

**On XBOX 360 or PS 3, *hold* the camera button and then zoom in the camera.**

Play around with it going left / right / up / down, you should eventually be able to zoom in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That was great!! I was so angry at getting stuck in first person view. I liked the fact that I could switch between the 2 views and when it was glitched I felt so stuck. I appreciated your answer it was so easy to fix. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 2):

(Note: I play on the PC) [This forum post](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/750181-dawnguard-kicked-to-3rd-person-constantly/page-2#entry6066167) has a solution requiring editing a save game file. I had the same problem and this is what fixed it.

> 1. Get a hex editor. I recommend XVI32.
> 2. Open up your "problem" Skyrim save in the hex editor.
> 3. Search for text string `dlc1playervampirechangescript`.
> 4. Change the `1` in that text to a `2`.
> 5. Save the file.
> 6. Enjoy Dawnguard in first person. :)

<sup>Source: [User DarkenDE's post at the Bethesda - Skyrim forums](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1403658-help-me-fix-the-dawnguard-3rd-person-bug/#entry21394808)</sup>

Comment: this worked for me