# Unable to change into first person camera mode

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some reason I cannot change into first person camera in Skyrim.

I've tried reassigning the button to no progress. Is this a bug that can be fixed or must I deal with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get out of third person view?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37265/how-do-i-get-out-of-third-person-view)

Comment: To the close voters: the other question deals with werewolf form. (Is there a way to take a close vote back?)

Answer (score 1):

Frequently I find I have to tap 'f' a few times or as noted above flick my mouse wheel back and forth before it will respond and slide into first person.

Comment: Have the same problem :(  Shouldn't be an issue seeing as other keys like Map work just fine. Also the camera is slow, and it will be "clamped" to the nearest wall, so while it is doing its "zoom in" animation sometimes you have the impression it's not working when it's not close enough yet, and you press twice and that makes things worse >_>

Answer (score 1):

Try this mod: **[Dawnguard 3rd person Fix](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22620/?)**.

> A small command line tool to fix the "Stuck in Third person" bug occurring to some people in Dawnguard...
>
> This bug is for some reason caused by a stuck "dlc1playervampirechangescript" inside the savegame, it is easily fixed with a hex editor, but for people who do not know how to use them i made this.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the game from a previous save. If it doesn't work the first time, try at least 3 times. This is not a guaranteed fix.

Answer (score -1):

PS3 user here. Had the same problem. Went into werewolf form. Then when I changed back, it was working again.