# Weird POV glitch in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I was playing Skyrim (with mods) and I have this character I tried some mods with, animation mods to be exact. Everything was all and well until I got stuck in 3rd person view, not like I can't go back to 1st person, I *can* go back, but it won't let me stay there. I have problems with the bow because I can't aim that well in 3rd.

I did some research, I read someones else's post about a glitch that sounded very similar, many replied and said it could only be fixed with a previous save, Unfortunately my last save was 27 levels back. I know it's small, but if you played Skyrim that long it would be a nightmare to go back a lot of levels.

I uploaded a video on YouTube about this glitch here it is:

Is there a way to solve this without loading an older save?

Comment: So does going back to a previous save fix the issue?

Comment: Also, there's a fix or two at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37265/how-do-i-get-out-of-third-person-view).

Comment: It fixes the issue from what I heard. This glitch does not affect my other saves though, I made a new save and there was nothing wrong with the POV. I tried downloading Save tool mod from nexus and it cleans up the saves, I tried it nothing changed.

Comment: @SEBASSZCHAN Have you tried [hex editing the save game as mentioned here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/176738/4797)?

Comment: no, I'll try it out.

Comment: Frank, I tried turning it on, the controls were messed up, I pressed f and scrolled. Didn't work, but thanks man.

Comment: OMG, It worked @galacticninja thanks so much guys. If you'll excuse me, Imma go kill some Imperials. Thanks again. ! ! !

Comment: Anyone know how to close this thread? I'm new, sorry.

Comment: @SEBASSZCHAN I'll be voting to close this thread now. Remember to upvote [the answer that has helped you](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/176738/4797).